# View function won't run on Etherscan but it runs in Remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, etherscan, goerli

Hey guys I have a strange issue regarding reading functions on goerli Etherscan.
I have a verified contract on Görli Etherscan
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xf01eE0f988e6613165A82C23aC5A5b0b6458E672
and when I try to access "viewMessages" function on Etherscan it gets rejected. Of course it doesn't work via Web3 Python Library either.When I try do it via Remix, it normally works. I have the access of viewMessages restricted only to authorised addresses, but as you can clearly see on the pictures. I am accessing it from the authorised address.

Can you please help me out?

[image]
[image]

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Messenger{

address [] public authorisedAddresses;

struct User {
    address sender;
    string message;
}
constructor(){
    authorisedAddresses.push(msg.sender);
}

User[] internal user;

function authoriseAddress(address _input) external {
    bool address_bool = verifyAddress();
    if (address_bool == true){
        authorisedAddresses.push(_input);
    }
    else {revert("User not authorised!");}
}
function writeMessage(string calldata _input) external {
    bool address_bool = verifyAddress();
    if (address_bool == true){
        user.push(User(msg.sender, _input));
    }
    else {revert("User not authorised!");}
}
function userLength() public view returns (uint) {
    return user.length;
}
function addressLength() internal view returns (uint) {
    return authorisedAddresses.length;
}
function verifyAddress() internal view returns (bool) {
    uint i = 0;
    while (i <= addressLength()){
        if (authorisedAddresses[i] == msg.sender) {
            return true;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return false;
}
function viewMessages(uint _input) public view returns(address, string memory){
    bool address_bool = verifyAddress();
    if (address_bool == true){
        User storage text = user[_input];
        return (text.sender, text.message);
    }
    else {revert("User not authorised!");}
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think etherscan uses your metamask when using 'read contract' methods. They probably use a generic address(0) as sender. You should verify by implementing a function `readMsgSender() external view returns(address)` that just returns `msg.sender` and check the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [0xSanson](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/75850/0xsanson) correctly guessed in the comment, the MetaMask address is in fact **not** relayed to the contract during the read-only call. Instead, calls have the address 0 as the `msg.sender`.

I was able to verify this scenario with a [custom contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xec54b2d9ce77c104f13be23d8adc9729805d754d#readContract).

So, the reason why the call revers, is because the `msg.sender` (value `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`) is not in the `authorisedAddresses` list, which effectively returns `false` from `verifyAddress()` and throws the `revert` in `viewMessages()`.